# Determinating the angle in a triangle

Tags: geometry

Determine the value of the angle $\alpha$ of the figure below.

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? Which angles have you been able to determine?

Comment: Hello Cameron I have determinated the angles $\angle DFC$, $\angle DFE$,  $\angle DEF$, $\angle FBC$, $\angle DAC$

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that is notoriously difficult to solve using elementary techniques. You might want to look at [this solution.](http://www.duckware.com/tech/worldshardesteasygeometryproblem.html)

For more information (and there is a lot) look under **adventitious angles.** The problem seems have been first published by Langley, so that could be another useful search term.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that I have solved before on my blog. I just post the solution and you will find the paths.

Hint: see $BFD$ equilateral triangle.

[image]