# How do I find $x$ in the following figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Can anyone help me out in finding the value of x in the following figure??[image]

While drawing i missed out a value. $\angle DCA = 20^{\circ}$. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: The angle in the middle point can't be $50^{\circ}$

Comment: Look up "adventitious angles". See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548292/determinating-the-angle-in-a-triangle

Comment: @GerryMyerson How come, so quick :) That was really helpful

Comment: @MatG88 Why do you think this?

Comment: @Momo Because it is an obtuse angle