# Euclidean Geometry: Find the value of angle $x$ in a nested triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

I have to find the value of $x$ and I did it and found out $x=40^0$. I used the cot theorem to find it. but without trigonometry is there a purely geometric proof? every single time I tried I was stopped at $x+F\hat BD=80^0$. Any hint or a proof would be appreciated.

P.S this is different from Langley’s Adventitious Angles problem since $CE \neq AC$
I saw some basic constructions led me to have some cyclic quadrilaterals. but they also did not gave me the answer

Comment: @fleablood But someone told me that this can be proved with only using elementary construction, cyclic quadrilateral, and similar triangles.

Comment: The question has been asked (and answered) here several times. Search here, or on the web, for "adventitious angles". For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548292/determinating-the-angle-in-a-triangle and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle)

Comment: Perhaps there's some manipulation of angles. Afterall you have 30 which is half of sixty.  But it's not obvious.  Why *not* use trig.  They teach the trig definitions and law of sines/cosines in most geometry classes these days.

Answer (score 3):

In this picture, there are some things that have to be further explained:

First of all, we take the symmetry of $\Delta BEC$. Then we draw a line from $B$ to $B'$ in order to have an equilateral triangle $\Delta BEB'$. Then we have the equality $|EB| = |BB'| = |EB'| = |AB|$. Here, since $\angle EBB' = 60^\circ$ and $|AB| = |BB'|$, we can conclude that $A$, $F$, $D$ and $B'$ are linear and $\angle AB'B = 20^\circ$. Then by noticing the fact that $EO$ is median of the equilateral triangle, it is median of $\Delta BDB'$ as well, which implies that $\angle DBB' = 20^\circ$. Therefore $x = 40^\circ$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy to see that
$$\measuredangle DBC=20^{\circ}+x$$ and $$\measuredangle EBD=80^{\circ}-x.$$
Thus, by law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{ED}{DC}=\frac{\frac{ED}{BD}}{\frac{DC}{BD}}=\frac{\frac{\sin(80^{\circ}-x)}{\sin30^{\circ}}}{\frac{\sin(20^{\circ}+x)}{\sin50^{\circ}}}=\frac{2\sin(80^{\circ}-x)\sin50^{\circ}}{\sin(20^{\circ}+x)}.$$
In another hand,
$$\frac{ED}{DC}=\frac{\frac{ED}{AD}}{\frac{DC}{AD}}=\frac{\frac{\sin30^{\circ}}{\sin80^{\circ}}}{\frac{\sin20^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}}=\frac{\sin50^{\circ}}{2\sin80^{\circ}\sin20^{\circ}}.$$
Thus,
$$4\sin20^{\circ}\sin80^{\circ}\sin(80^{\circ}-x)=\sin(20^{\circ}+x)$$  or
$$2(\cos60^{\circ}-\cos100^{\circ})\sin(80^{\circ}-x)=\sin(20^{\circ}+x)$$ or
$$\sin(80^{\circ}-x)+\sin(160^{\circ}-x)-\sin{x}=\sin(20^{\circ}+x)$$ or
$$\sin(80^{\circ}-x)=\sin{x},$$ which gives $$x=40^{\circ}.$$

Comment: I did it with trigonometry. but i want a geometric proof

Comment: @thomson By the ArsenBerk's picture we can get a right geometric solution.